# TDOA calculation, scipy minimize overshoot sometime

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, calculation

I am trying to use TDOA to find the sound source location in a coordinate system.

We have a costfunction looks like this:

```
    def costfunction(point, meas_list, dims=2):
        #### Cost function to be fed into the scipy.optimize.minimize function
        #### For a candidate point, calculates the time differences, compares it
        #### to data
        error = 0
        for m in meas_list:
            actualdiff = m.delta
            calcdiff = (
                m.soundpointB.dist(point, dims=dims)
                - m.soundpointA.dist(point, dims=dims)
                )
            
            error += (actualdiff - calcdiff) ** 2
    
        return(error)
```

```
soundpointB.dist #---> is to calculate the distance between sensors
```

our sensor location is

```
b = [-2, 2,0]
c = [2,-2,0]
d = [2,2,0]
e = [0,0,2]
```

we simulate random source in range -50 to 50 in x,y and 0 to -20 in z
the simulation would generate time difference from the source to each sensor.

so we have the cost function to calculate the mean square error
Then we use scipy minimize to find out the best solution

```
    startpoint = np.array([0,0,0])
    dims = 3
    result = minimize(
            fun=costfunction,
                x0=startpoint,
                args=(meas_list, dims),
                method='BFGS',
                  options={
                      'gtol': 1e-06,
                      'return_all':True,
                      'norm':inf},
                jac='2-point')
```

For most of the calculation are good, the %error between the actual position and TDOA calculated position is +-10%

However for some location like [-30.0, 0.5, -6.0], the TDOA calculation return [-325.07,5.49,-64.73]

When we check all result from the scipy minimize. it seems it already found the location but it overshoot.

Does anyone know how to make this better? or something need to be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BFGS will not guarantee anything but a local minimum. If you know that your sensors will always be between -50 and 50 and -2 and 2, then I would suggest:

- As a first step, try a bounded local minimization - using L-BFGS-B, SLSQP, etc... and give your variables those bounds
- If the above is not satisfactory enough, bring out the big artillery and try global optimization algorithms, such as SHGO, DifferentialEvolution, DualAnnealing. They are all available in SciPy, might be slower but you’ll be much more confident in your results.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But the situation seems the actual answer is before the minimum. Does it mean that I have a bad cost function?

Comment: Potentially yes: if your model says that the best parameters values are at the location of the random sensor, then your cost function needs to reflect that: since it’s a sum of squares, if the optimizer finds the correct parameters the objective function should be zero at that point.